# onClick(), I want to add table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add row on every click, but my code is replacing the same row.

Also tried to keep `if` outside addTable function but this did not work for me.

I tried many solutions but failed. Could anyone please help me here?

I have added my code below, Please check and let me know.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const App = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  var [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  function addTable() {
    setCount(count + 1);
    if (count <= 10) {
      setItems(
        <tr>
          <td>5 x {count}</td>
          <td>{5 * count}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="button">
        <button onClick={addTable}>
          Click to generate Multiplication tables of 5{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Multiplication</th>
            <th>Results</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{items}</tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: Pushing JSX into state is generally not a good approach, and that maybe where the problem is.

Comment: You should be adding items to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're overwriting items in your onChange, you need to append to it:

```
setItems([
    ...items,
    <tr>
      <td>5 x {count}</td>
      <td>{5 * count}</td>
    </tr>
]);
```

But I would probably do instead is:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const App = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  var [counts, setCounts] = useState([]);
  function addTable() {
    setCount(count + 1);
    if (count <= 10) setCounts([...counts, count]);
  }
  console.log(count);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="button">
        <button onClick={addTable}>
          Click to generate Multiplication tables of 5{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Multiplication</th>
            <th>Results</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{counts.map((c) => (
          <tr>
            <td>5 x {c}</td>
            <td>{5 * c}</td>
          </tr>
        )}</tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The above snippet worked for me. Thanks for that. 
I want to understand about `counts` in below code snippet.  Could you please share some points on this?

Comment: Okay, counts is same as items in my code.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setItems` you're replacing the current state with the new row.

I've removed the section that adds JSX to state (and removed that state altogether) and replaced it with two values: the current times table value, and an upper limit.

The new function `getRows` then has a simple loop that adds JSX to an array and returns that instead.

(Additionally I've disabled the button when the count exceeds the limit so you can't add any more rows.)

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  
  // New constants
  const timesTable = 5;
  const limit = 10;
  
  // One state
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  // The button updates the count
  function updateCount() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  // And we have a simple loop to push the right
  // number of rows into an array which is
  // then returned
  function getRows(count) {
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      rows.push(
        <tr class="row">
          <td>{timesTable} x {i}</td>
          <td>{timesTable * i}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
    return rows;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="button">
        <button
          disabled={count > limit}
          onClick={updateCount}
        >Add row to {timesTable}x table
        </button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Multiplication</th>
            <th>Result</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {getRows(count)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.button { margin-bottom: 1em; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
th { text-transform: uppercase; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #efefef; }
td, th { padding: 4px 8px; }
td { border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```